# Printing out a tree set using pattern matching in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm working on some exercises Scala by Example and I've implemented an excl() method on sets which removes an element from a set, and a toString method that converts a set to a string.

I'm practicing use pattern matching here. A bit concerned about shadowing my instance variables on the line

`case NonEmptySet(elem, left, right)`

Is there anything obvious that could be improved?

```
trait IntSet {
  def incl(x: Int): IntSet
  def excl(x: Int): IntSet
  def contains(x: Int): Boolean
}

case object EmptySet extends IntSet {
  def contains(x: Int): Boolean = false
  def incl(x: Int): IntSet = new NonEmptySet(x, EmptySet, EmptySet)
  def excl(x: Int) = this
  override def toString = "{}"
}

case class NonEmptySet(elem: Int, left: IntSet, right: IntSet) extends IntSet {
  def contains(x: Int): Boolean =
    if (x < elem) left contains x
      else if (x > elem) right contains x
      else true
  def incl(x: Int): IntSet =
    if (x < elem) NonEmptySet(elem, left incl x, right)
      else if (x > elem) NonEmptySet(elem, left, right incl x)
      else this
  def excl(x: Int): IntSet = {
    def combine(left: IntSet, right: IntSet): IntSet = {
      left match {
        case EmptySet => right
        case NonEmptySet(elem, ll, lr) => NonEmptySet(elem, combine(ll, lr), right)
      }
    }
    if (x < elem) new NonEmptySet(elem, left excl x, right)
    else if (x > elem) new NonEmptySet(elem, left, right excl x)
    else combine(left, right)
  }
  override def toString(): String = {
    def listElements(comma: Boolean, set: IntSet) : String = {
      set match {
        case EmptySet => ""
        case NonEmptySet(elem, left, right) => {
          val rightPart = elem + listElements(true, right)
          val list = left match {
            case EmptySet => rightPart
            case NonEmptySet(le, ll, lr) => listElements(false, left) + ", " + rightPart
          }
          (if (comma) ", " else "") + list
        }
      }
    }
    '{' + listElements(false, this) + '}'
  }

}



var subset = EmptySet incl 2
var set = subset incl 3 incl 4 incl 8 incl 9 incl 10 incl 11 excl 4
println(set contains 6)
println(set.contains(6))
println(set contains 2)
println(set incl 4 incl 6 excl 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ideas:

- Make the trait `sealed`.
- `combine` doesn't need to be a nested function, this only makes it harder to read and causes problems with shadowed variables. Instead you could move it to an accompanying object, or make it a separate method such as:

  ```
  sealed trait IntSet {
      ...
      private def combine(withRight: IntSet): IntSet;
  }
  ```

  for `EmptySet` it will just return `withRight`, for a `NonEmptySet` it will be

  ```
   def combine(withRight: IntSet): IntSet =
      NonEmptySet(elem, left.combine(right), withRight);
  ```
- `toString` is somewhat complicated, and can suffer from performance problems due to repeatedly concatenating strings together. Instead I'd suggest you to implement [`Traversable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Traversable). Not only this will make your class much more useful, it's implementation will be cleaner, because it won't be cluttered by operating with strings. And then you'll already have `mkString` which you can use as

  ```
  override def toString: String = mkString("{", ",", "}")
  ```